# How to make an array to clear the checkbox in "register_setting"?

Tags: wordpress

There is a ready form.
2 checkboxes, everything works, but how to make an array when there are a lot of checkboxes?

```
<?php
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'add_page' );
function add_page() {
    add_options_page( 'Test Settings', 'Title', 'manage_options', 'page_slug', 'callback_output' );
}

function callback_output() {
    ?>
<div class="wrap">
<form action="options.php" method="post">
    <?php
    settings_fields( 'option_group' );
    do_settings_sections( 'field_page' );
    submit_button();
    ?>
</form>
</div>
    <?php
}

add_action( 'admin_init', 'settings' );
function settings() {
    register_setting( 'option_group', 'db_settings', 'sinitize' );

    add_settings_section( 'sect_id', 'Settings', '', 'field_page' );

    add_settings_field( 'field1', 'NAME FIELD 1', 'fill_field1', 'field_page', 'sect_id' );
    add_settings_field( 'field2', 'NAME FIELD 2', 'fill_field2', 'field_page', 'sect_id' );
}

function fill_field1() {
    $val = get_option( 'db_settings' );
    $val = $val ? $val['checkbox1'] : false;
    ?>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="db_settings[checkbox1]" value="1" <?php checked( 1, $val ); ?> /> checkbox 1</label>
    <?php
}

function fill_field2() {
    $val = get_option( 'db_settings' );
    $val = $val ? $val['checkbox2'] : false;
    ?>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="db_settings[checkbox2]" value="1" <?php checked( 1, $val ); ?> /> checkbox 2</label>
    <?php
}

**// Sinitize. Need array.**
function sinitize( $options ) {
    foreach ( $options as $name => & $val ) {
        if ( 'checkbox1' === $name ) {
            $val = int( $val );
        } elseif ( 'checkbox2' === $name ) {
            $val = int( $val );
        }
    }
    return $options;
}
```

How can I just do this without changing the main code, just changing the function: *sinitize()*
Thanks in advance for your replies!

Answer (score 0):

To start with, I don't believe you're using [register_setting](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_setting/) correctly - the third parameter should be an array of args, not a callback reference.

Within the $args array, you can specify 'type' as 'array' - that may be what you're looking for.